# Which one is best scenario to parse data from server (net) in android

Tags: android

In my app i have to parse data from server.I have seen in some sites,some of examples using `AsyncTask`, some of examples using some callback methods,some of examples using threads and handlers.

which one is best to parse data from server.

Comment: Your question is little misleading.

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html

Comment: Your question is clearly not making any sense...Parsing data and using Async tasks are two whole different topics....Parsing means when you get response from server then you need to parse it from XML, JSON or SOAP to use it in your application and Async tasks are used to to do heavy processing in background thread so that UI thread does not hangs.

Comment: Question makes perfect sense to me (other than the extraneous . in the title) and seems motivated by an implicit awareness of a rule of android development which all the responses so far miss: that network operations have to be done in the background.

Answer (score 3):

AsyncTasks, Threads and Handlers have absolutely nothing to do with **parsing data**, they just allow you to move long-running processing tasks away from the UI thread. Anyway, for beginners I'd recommend `AsyncTask` as well documented, supported and most widely used in Android environment.

Comment: Actually, they have a lot to do with parsing data **from the network** in that you aren't supposed to do network operations on the UI thread.  Anything one can't guarantee will complete very quickly has to be considered a potentially longer running task.